# Multiple UIButtons for One WebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uibutton, xcode6.1

I am looking for a quicker method to build my application. As i have a series of buttons that are all going to open a UIWebView. But, I want to be able to use only One (1) WebView. I also want to be able to have the Buttons in a different View Controller.

So my question is, How would you get buttons to go from one view controller into another view controller that has a web viewer in it, and still be able to get different weblink's to load from the buttons?

I am still new to the programing community. I am doing this all as self teaching also.

Thank You guys!

Comment: I revised my question.

Comment: could I please have the "Hold" removed?

Comment: You have the web view in the same controller as the buttons. Is that what you want?

Comment: @DanielT. The buttons I want in a different View Controller, But to be able to pull up the provided URL

Comment: Sorry, my rep isn't high enough to break the hold so I can't post my answer. Frankly, I don't think my answer would help you much anyway. Yes, it does what you asked to do, but it won't teach you anything. Your posted code is so messed up that the compiler is crashing trying to read it. Do this: Remove all the `fun loadAddressURL()` definitions except the first one. Then learn about how to call a function and call `loadAddressURL()` from the action functions instead of redefining it every time.

Comment: I am currently right now cleaning up the code. I was able to obtain some information on how to go about doing it. With all the buttons in the same viewer. Now I want to be able to get the buttons out and have them in a different View Controller and still be able to do the same thing.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6727379 follow this link for an updated version of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one xib which will contain one UIWebView and buttons
and in target method of buttons, you assign the new url are reload the webView

As mentioned below

```
-(void)reloadWebVieWithUrl:(NSString *)strUrl
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.wbView loadRequest:request];
}

- (IBAction)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *url = @"";

    switch (sender.tag) {
        case 100:
        {
            url = @"https://www.google.co.in/";
            break;
        }
        case 101:
        {
            url = @"https://in.yahoo.com/";

            break;
        }
        case 102:
        {
            url = @"https://www.facebook.com/";

            break;
        }
        case 103:
        {
            url = @"http://stackoverflow.com/";

            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }

    [self reloadWebVieWithUrl:url];
}
```

In Swift

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var wbView: UIWebView!
    var strUrl = ""

    @IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {

        switch (sender.tag){
        case 100:
            strUrl = "https://www.google.co.in/"

        case 101:
            strUrl = "https://in.yahoo.com/"

        case 102:
            strUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/"

        case 103:
            strUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com/"

        default:
            break;
        }

        reloadWebViewWithUrl(strUrl);
    }

    func reloadWebViewWithUrl(strUrl: NSString){
        var url = NSURL(string: strUrl);
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url);

        wbView.loadRequest(request);
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: I would put the strings in an array and use the button tag to index into the array, but otherwise I think this is a good answer.

Comment: Janmenjaya, I am doing what you told me to do, but Now it is throwing an error saying "Expected declaration". What would that be?

Comment: @AllenSchuenke,Sorry I do not know swift, to identify your issue, But i guess you are doing something wrong in declaring variable or properties. Go through this link, it may help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479700/expected-declaration-error-creating-array-in-viewcontroller-cant-work-out-why

Comment: @DanielT. Would you be willing to show how you would do it for me please? I am messing around with this code and keep getting nothing but errors with it.

Comment: @AllenSchuenke, Hey I am editing my answer here in swift also. Use this and you will able to run. I am also new bee to Swift, but i tried it in my system and I found it working. Accept the answer if you find it useful. Or let me know if some problem would be there

Comment: @Janmenjaya, This works as long as the buttons are on the same view controller. Its a great start. Now what I need to have happen is, to get those buttons outside of the view controller and have them in a separate view controller. lol. I need to go from one view controller and be able to have the same links to work through a segue to the second view controller which will have the Web Viewer

Comment: @AllenSchuenke, Then you take a string value in the destination view controller to pass the sting URL from the source Controller based on the button click. And in the destination controller reload the webView according the string URL. Just try with this concept, i guess you can do it.

Comment: @Janmenjaya I am doing what you are telling me to do but every time I go to run it and click on the button it keeps coming up with a fatal error with trying to unwrap "reloadWebViewWithUrl(strUrl);"

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: discussions.apple.com/thread/6727379 follow this link for an updated version of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple webviews or VC's to do this.

You can just change the NSURL to reflect the website you want to navigate the user to.

So for example the action for button one could be :

```
NSString *webSite = "@http://google.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webSite];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSUrLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Then for button two - use the same code, using the same webView and just change the string to the website you want to navigate the user to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like the simplicity of what you sent to me. I am just wondering how you would put that into a full code!